# Content left align broken in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm having trouble aligning my content correctly in IE9. I never did like IE, and used to just ban it from my sites, but I need it now. How can I fix this while keeping the same feel in Chrome?

Here you can see the broken content http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/index.html I tried a couple fixes for IE but they break in chrome. :\

The second box, with the nav bar on the right, the content that is suppose to be on the left is pushed under the nav bar. :\

**HTML**

```
<div class="large-box">
    <div class="large-box-content">
        <div class="content-right">
            <div class="column-header">
                <div class="column-icon">
                    Title here
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <div class="column-header">
                <div class="column-icon">
                    Title here
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-left">
            <div class="column-header">
                <div class="column-icon">
                    Title here
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <div class="column-header">
                <div class="column-icon">
                    Title here
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
            <p>Some content here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.large-box {
    display: block;
    transition: height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    width: 74%;
    min-width: 990px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto 20px;
    background-image: url(images/nav-trans.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border: 1px solid #242f3e;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #121417;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #121417;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #121417;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=14, Direction=0, Color='#121417')";
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.large-box:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

.large-box-content {
    height: 100%;
}

.content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-image: url(images/blue-trans.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-left: 1px solid #1b232e;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 3px rgba(18, 25, 39, 0.10);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 0px 3px rgba(18, 25, 39, 0.10);
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 3px rgba(18, 25, 39, 0.10);
}

.content-left {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: It's fine on my IE9.. Which part is broken exactly?

Comment: The second box, with the nav bar on the right, the content is pushed under the nav bar. :\

Comment: This is what i see on my screen, using IE9: http://imgur.com/vrHH9dR

Comment: I think the size of your screen is pushing the content underneath..

Comment: That is interesting. This is what I see http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/5651/94331609.jpg

Comment: I checked it in IE9, Forefox and Chrome, and see no difference. There are some things missing in IE8, but not the content bug that you mention. In IE7 I see the content behaving as you describe.

Comment: Weird. I have IE9, I just upgraded to ensure that while installing Opera, Firefox, and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `content-right` has `width` as 300px and `border-left` as `1px` so the total width is `301px`. So in `content-left`, you need to give `margin-right` as `301px` instead of `300px`.

```
.content-left {
 height: auto;
 padding: 0;
 margin-right: 301px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Good eye, that must be it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the width of 'content-left' div to a fixed width instead of letting IE9 figure it out for itself.

**Example:**

**CSS:**

```
.content-left {
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1105px;
}
```

Comment: I'd love to if it wasn't a dynamic layout.

Comment: IEs have their own version of a dynamic layout

Comment: No they don't... it's the same 100% or simply not. My size was just off. That's a case from the past. IE6 and Below.

Comment: I was just being sarcastic ;) My experience with IE8 and using percentage as measurement units is really bad.
Hope you manage to solve your problem.